# Can't get gcc version from to switch from 4.2.1 to 4.6 even after selecting it (MacPorts)

Tags: gcc, version, macports

I'm running Snow Leopard and need to compile something using a more recent version of GCC than 4.2.1. I've been using MacPorts but can't seem to get the command-line GCC to recognize the MacPorts version:

```
[15:01:47] ~/Downloads$
port select gcc
Available versions for gcc:
gcc40
gcc42
llvm-gcc42
mp-gcc44
mp-gcc45
mp-gcc46 (active)
none
[15:10:04] ~/Downloads$
sudo port select gcc mp-gcc46
Selecting 'mp-gcc46' for 'gcc' succeeded. 'mp-gcc46' is now active.
[15:10:24] ~/Downloads$
sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc46
Selecting 'mp-gcc46' for 'gcc' succeeded. 'mp-gcc46' is now active.
[15:11:34] ~/Downloads$
gcc -version
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
[15:11:40] ~/Downloads$
```

Even though I use MacPorts select to specify a newer version, that switch does not seem to do anything (even after rebooting, etc.). I feel like I'm missing something very simple but I have looked in multiple places for some help on remedying this without luck.

Thanks!

Comment: I should add that what I need to compile is run by an scons script...I can't just use the command 'gcc-mp-4.6'. I realize that Xcode doesn't like using other versions of GCC but I don't understand why there would be no way to change the default version in Terminal, or if there weren't, what the point of the 'port select' command even is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind everybody. I changed my .bashrc file so that, in the PATH, the Mac ports directories come before /usr/bin instead of after.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I tried editing the PATH like you said, but it hasn't fixed the problem.  When I type in `echo $PATH` I get `.:/opt/local/var/macports:/usr/local/bin:/sw/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/hallamsoft:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin`.  Any other ideas?